# Mapping a function over n levels

Tags: functions, matrix, map

I want to map a function over a matrix of rank n, for example:

```
PercentChange[v_?VectorQ] := Differences@v/Most@v*100
PercentChange[v_] := Map[PercentChange, v, {Length@Dimensions@v-1}]

m = N@Range@10;

PercentChange /@ {m, {m, m}, {{m, m}, {m, m}}}
```

This works as expected.

Now, as a lazy beginner, I thought that I could get rid of the duplicate definition of "PercentChange" and simply state:

```
PercentChange[v_] := Map[PercentChange, v, {Length@Dimensions@v - 1}]
```

However, to my disappointment this didn' t function  because "Map"  doesn't accept a level {0} parameter:

```
Map[Differences@m/Most@m, m, {0}]*100
```

On the other hand, this functions in all cases:

```
Percent2[v_] := Map[Differences@#/Most@# &, v, {Length@Dimensions@v-1}]*100
```

How would you write this without duplication and slot-notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion that `Map` does not accept a *levelspec* of `{0}` is incorrect:

```
Map[f, bar[1, 2, 3], {0}]
```

> ```
> f[bar[1, 2, 3]]
> ```

For your second definition:

```
Percent2[v_] := Map[Differences@#/Most@# &, v, {Length@Dimensions@v-1}]*100
```

Which duplication are you referring to, and why don't you like `Slot` notation?

Anyway, if you are merely looking for a different style perhaps:

```
fn[v_?VectorQ] := Differences@v / Most@v * 100
fn[a_?ArrayQ]  := fn /@ a

fn[{a, b, c}]
fn[{{a, b, c}, {q, r, s}}]
```

> ```
> {(100 (-a + b))/a, (100 (-b + c))/b}
>
> {{(100 (-a + b))/a, (100 (-b + c))/b}, {(100 (-q + r))/q, (100 (-r + s))/r}}
> ```

Also `ArrayDepth[v] - {1}` is a little cleaner than `{Length @ Dimensions @ v - 1}`.

Although far less clean in my opinion, we could also take advantage of the second parameter of `Differences`, and use a substitute for `Most`, to perform this operation without an explicit `Map`.

```
fn2[a_?ArrayQ] :=
 With[{depth = PadLeft[{1}, ArrayDepth[a]]},
   Differences[a, depth] / Part[a, ##] * 100 & @@ (depth /. {0 -> All, 1 -> ;; -2})
 ]
```

Test:

```
m = N @ Range @ 10;
lists = {m, {m, m}, {{m, m}, {m, m}}};
fn /@ lists === fn2 /@ lists
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: (1) Just try "Map[Differences@m/Most@m*100, m, {0}]" with the above definition of "m" - it doesn't function. (2) With "duplication" I meant the initial definition of "PercentChange" (lines 1 and 2 of my question).

Comment: @eldo The problem with `Map[Differences@m/Most@m*100, m, {0}]` is that the first argument is not a function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me ;)

Comment: @eldo The "wink" suggests to me that you say that sarcastically; if that is the case I genuinely don't know what you're looking for and I am trying to be helpful.  If however I misunderstand you are welcome.  Either way I will attempt to answer more questions if I am able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: The "wink" was a polite smile

Comment: @eldo Okay. :-)