# Applying a function along the desired dimensions of a n-dimensional array

Tags: functions, map, list-manipulation

I am trying to apply an arbitrary function `f` that takes several inputs and returns a scalar along some specific dimensions of an n-dimensionnal array.

Here is an example of how I proceed for now (supposing the arbitrary function `f` is `Mean` ) :

```
aa = {ConstantArray[1, 4], ConstantArray[2, 4], ConstantArray[3, 4]};
a = {aa, aa, aa};
```

Suppose I want the mean of `a` along the dimension (or should I say level?) 2, I do :

```
Table[Mean[a[[ii, ;;, jj]] ], {ii, Dimensions[a][[1]]} , {jj, Dimensions[a][[3]]} ]
```

Which yields :
    `{{2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}`
as expected.

I would like to implement a function that would enable me to compute any function `f` (that takes several inputs and spits out a scalar just like `Mean` does) over any arbitrary set of the dimensions of a n-dimensionnal array.

I feel like I could do something with `Map` and recursive functions such as [there]{[Mapping a function over n levels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47990/mapping-a-function-over-n-levels)} but I fail to see how to do. Or maybe this is not the right way to do it...

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Map[f@@##&, expr, {level}]`? Or just `Map[f, expr, {level}]`, depending on whether `f` actually takes **one** list, or a `Sequence` of values. Here we can reproduce your result with a simple `Map[Mean, a, {1}]` or `Mean /@ a`...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I guess it could be something of the kind, however if I naively try your suggestion adapted to my example : `Map[Mean @@ ## &, a, 2]` it doesn't yield the expected value.

Comment: That's because `Mean` does **not** take several input arguments, but **one** list of arguments. The lists you are passing to `Mean` in your `Table` are lists of all elements at level 2, for a given first index `ii`... But those lists _are_ what you find at level 1! So just `Mean /@ a` is what you need in your example, as I've written above.

Comment: If you can make an example of a function that needs a sequence of several arguments, and not a list of arguments, (one argument), then we can try to deal with that.

Comment: `Mean /@ a` indeed works for this specific example which I voluntarily kept simple (maybe too simple then), but it does not apply for any set of levels as I required further in the question. As for your remark about `Mean` that takes **one** list of arguments, thanks for pointing that out ! That is indeed what I would like to have : a function that takes one list of scalar arguments and spits out a single scalar. The problem lies in defining that list in a general and versatile way.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer (I forgot to tag you)